# Jira sync tasks from other Jira

Tags: jira

I have two Jira instances (both are Jira Cloud) and the same project in both.

Historically one Jira is used by dev team and second Jira is used by ops.

However, some dev tasks have to be considered by ops team.

So the question: is it possible to sync issues from one Jira to other Jira?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to sync issues from one Jira to another, however, this will require you to install additional add-ons to your Jira instances.

In the marketplace you have several available solutions:

- [Backbone Issue Sync for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1215199/backbone-issue-sync-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview)
- [Exalate Jira Issue Sync & more](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1213645/exalate-jira-issue-sync-more?hosting=cloud&tab=overview)
- [Issue SYNC - Synchronization for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1213346/issue-sync-synchronization-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview)

You can trial all of them and pick one that suits you the most. Or in extreme case, if you have some programming skills you could develop such add-on yourself, however, if you include maintenance and hosting costs it's probably cheaper to buys an existing solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you are aware that you don't have that much flexibility in Cloud. However, check if Backbone Issue Sync plugin can help you or not. In Server it's possible to do it via Issue Sync Plugin.